# Pandas only printing last bs4 element to csv file

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping house data from [zoopla.co.uk](https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine)

The dataframe seems to be printing correctly, but pandas is printing only the last element (the last house) to the csv file.

I also tried casting each object as a list in the pd.DataFrame({}) statement but that did not change the csv output.

Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

my_url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine'
res = requests.get(my_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
lis = soup.find("ul", class_="listing-results clearfix js-gtm-list").find_all("li", class_="srp clearfix")

for li in lis:
    bedrooms = li.find("span", class_="num-beds")
    bathrooms = li.find("span", class_="num-baths")

    price = li.find("a", class_="text-price")
    house_price = re.findall('\£(\d+)', str(price))

    style = li.find("h2", class_="listing-results-attr")
    house_type = re.findall('(?<=bed ).*(?= for)', str(style))

    distance = li.find("li", class_="clearfix")
    station_distance = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', str(distance))

    if bedrooms:
        bedrooms = bedrooms.get_text(strip=True)
    if bathrooms:
        bathrooms = bathrooms.get_text(strip=True)
    if house_price:
        house_price = house_price
    if house_type:
        house_type = house_type
    if station_distance:
        station_distance = station_distance

    df = pd.DataFrame({'house_price': house_price, 'house_type': house_type, 'station_distance': station_distance, 'bedrooms': bedrooms, 'bathrooms': bathrooms})
    print(df)

    df.to_csv('zoopla.csv')
```

Output

```
house_price house_type station_distance bedrooms bathrooms
0          90       flat              0.2        1         1
  house_price      house_type station_distance bedrooms bathrooms
0         210  detached house              0.6        3      None
  house_price         house_type station_distance bedrooms bathrooms
0         160  end terrace house              0.7        2         1
  house_price      house_type station_distance bedrooms bathrooms
0         325  detached house              1.2        4         1
  house_price           house_type station_distance bedrooms bathrooms
0         195  semi-detached house              1.1        3         1
  house_price      house_type station_distance bedrooms bathrooms
0          24  terraced house              0.9        3      None
  house_price house_type station_distance bedrooms bathrooms
0         115       flat              0.2        2         1
```

Excel Output - pandas only outputs the last element (house) from web site
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-riding the dataframe with each iteration.

Use:

```
result = []
for li in lis:
    ...

    result.append({'house_price': house_price, 'house_type': house_type, 'station_distance': station_distance, 'bedrooms': bedrooms, 'bathrooms': bathrooms})
    
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)

df.to_csv('zoopla.csv')
```

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Oh sorry missed `.append`

Comment: My bad. I should've caught that because of the empty list.

Comment: Everything is good. I have a question about the df output. `[90]  [flat]  [0.2]  1  1`, `[210]  [detached house]  [0.6]  3  None`. How do I get rid of the list brackets? https://imgur.com/0E2tCbT